# Define a custom float8 in python-numpy and convert from/to float16?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, user-defined-data-types

I am trying to define a custom 8 bit floating point format as follows:

- 1 sign bit
- 2 bits for mantissa
- 5 bits for exponent

Is it possible to define this as a numpy datatype? 
If not, what is the easiest way to convert a numpy array of dtype float16 to such a format (for storage) and convert it back (for calculations in float16), maybe using the bit operations of numpy?

**Why:**

I am trying to optimize a neural network on custom hardware (FPGA). For this, I am playing around with various float representations. I have already built a forward pass framework for my neural network with numpy, therefore something like above will help me check the reduction in accuracy by storing the values in my custom datatype.

Comment: What is the size of the array/dataset you are trying to convert?

Comment: @Deepstop Something like 400x400x3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm by no means an expert in numpy, but I like to think about FP representation problems. The size of your array is not huge, so any reasonably efficient method should be fine. It doesn't look like there's an 8 bit FP representation, I guess because the precision isn't so good.

To convert to an array of bytes, each containing a single 8 bit FP value, for a single dimensional array, all you need is

```
float16 = np.array([6.3, 2.557])           # Here's some data in an array
float8s = array.tobytes()[1::2]
print(float8s)
>>> b'FAAF'
```

This just takes the high-order bytes from the 16 bit float by lopping off the low order part, giving a 1 bit sign, 5 bit exponent and 2 bit significand. The high order byte is always the second byte of each pair on a little-endian machine. I've tried it on a 2D array and it works the same. This truncates. Rounding in decimal would be a whole other can of worms.

Getting back to 16 bits would be just inserting zeros. I found this method by experiment and there is undoubtedly a better way, but this reads the byte array as 8 bit integers and writes a new one as 16 bit integers and then converts it back to an array of floats. Note the big-endian representation converting back to bytes as we want the 8 bit values to be the high order bytes of the integers.

```
float16 = np.frombuffer(np.array(np.frombuffer(float8s, dtype='u1'), dtype='>u2').tobytes(), dtype='f2')
print(float16)
>>> array([6. , 2.5, 2.5, 6. ], dtype=float16)
```

You can definitely see the loss of precision! I hope this helps. If this is sufficient, let me know. If not, I'd be up for looking deeper into it.

Comment: This is amazing! I'll give it a try asap. Can you tell me what dtype='f2', '>u2' and 'u1' do? I have never seen them before

Comment: I've got this question on floating points to which I'm searching for an explaination for the past several months. Can you please take a look at that? Thanks in advance!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57016843/why-not-use-a-twos-complement-based-floating-point

Comment: `dtype = f2` is just short for `dtype=float16`. `>u2` is big-endian unsigned 16-bit (i.e. 2 byte) integer, and `u1` is 8-bit unsigned integer. They are listed at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Comment: Regarding your other questions that delves into hardware topics with which I'm unfamiliar. The answers there are considerably deeper than my knowledge of CPU design and FPGAs. I'm just a former assembly language programmer although I've done a little device interfacing nothing actually inside the chips. By the way, if the translation you wanted was anything more than just removing every other byte to truncate the low order bits, and the # of inputs was an order or two of magnitude higher, I'd be tempted to build a 2^16 length translation table and switch to a C function called from Python.

Comment: Great! I was considering to write a C function and call it from python. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I would like to experiment with different sizes for mantissas and exponents. I was thinking of using the bit operations of C++. I'm not quite sure how to write the 2^16 table. Can you give a basic idea on that?

Comment: There are 65536 combinations of 16 bits. That's all the possible float16. If you built an array 65536 bytes long, you could put all the translated values to any 8 bit floating point representation you choose. Then you use the value of your float as an unsigned integer as the index to the table. That way, the conversion is likely going to be a single machine instruction no matter how complex your mapping from float16 to float8 is. 64K bytes isn't much memory on today's machines, and could be stored on disk for re-use. So for very large conversions it would be very fast., especially in C.

Comment: I see. That could be way faster than doing bit manipulation every time. Thanks a lot